# How to make the Qt example text editor multi-tab?

Tags: qt, mdi

In the Qt 5.7 examples, there is one called "Qt Quick Controls - Text Editor Example". I wonder what can I change to add tabs so that it can open multiple documents at the same time, each under one tab. Thank you.

[image: Qt 5.7 text editor example]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: look up some examples using the QTabWidget.